# how to remove posts with specific label from blogger search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

How do you remove posts with specific label from blogger search results. I don't want to remove the blog posts from google search results. I just want to hide them from my website visitor

I dont want to remove them from my homepage I want to remove them from search result

[here is my blogger template](https://uptobox.com/1wl5mdebisg9)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it , but it requires little understanding of Blogger template structure. Therefore before you proceed , Please backup your template by going to Template > Backup/Restore > Download Full Template , so that you can switch back to it if anything goes wrong while editing.

Go to Template tab in Blogger Dashboard and click the Edit HTML button. Now click once inside the Editor and then Press CTRL+F(Windows) or COMMAND+F(Mac) , A search box will appear in the right upper corner of the editor itself. Now search for this "" (without quotes - there will be only one instance of this) and you will see code like

```html
<div class='post-outer'>
*<b:include data='post' name='post'/>*
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
```

Now replace the above code between the stars  with

```html
   
*<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != &quot;*paper cuttings*&quot;'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />*
```

in the replaced code part between the stars(paper cuttings) is the label name that you want to hide from the homepage. Also for the above code to work , make sure the posts that you want to hide only have 1 label on them.
and now your visitors can't see the posts with that label.

Comment: I couldn't find this code '<div class='post-outer'>
*<b:include data='post' name='post'/>*
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>'

Comment: Go to theme and edit HTML and click CTRL+F and look <b:include data='post' name='post'/> it does exist and this what you must replace like i said replace what is between the stars * do not replace the whole code just <b:include data='post' name='post'/> with the code that i provide you .

Comment: The problem with this method is that creates empty white spaces in the home page. So it does not really hide the post space but just what's inside the post space. Is there any new method to totally hide the post space in home page? Thnx